# dynamodb query by hashkey+multiple range keys

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I want to query dynamoDB by hashkey+multiple range keys...
the DynamoDBQueryExpression is not ok for the api .I can not set multile range keys at the api level.what should I do

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? The Query API won't support this but there is a Batch GET API

Comment: @MrWiggles I just want to query by hashKey and multiple range keys to get some rows back.What batch method should I invoke?  I use the DynamoDBMapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DynamoDBMapper` has an API for retrieving multiple items from multiple tables based on the primary key, which is documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/dynamodbv2/datamodeling/DynamoDBMapper.html).

The method you're looking for is

```java
public java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.util.List<java.lang.Object>> 
         batchLoad(java.util.Map<java.lang.Class<?>,java.util.List<KeyPair>> itemsToGet)
```

Where the `KeyPair` will be used to list your Hash/Range keys

Comment: Yeah.I've found the solution as the above you sugested.thank you  so much @MrWiggles